# Hide object for particular condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am getting some data from object. So I have implemented object and storing multiple value in object in javascript But I want to hide particular object for specific condition.

**My Data:**

```
  $scope.sort={
    National :    { prop: "Country", classes: { md:2, lg:2, xs:1, sm:2} },
    'Passport #': { prop: "tNumber", classes: { md:2, lg:1, xs:2, sm:2}'},
    Name :        { prop: "name",    classes: { md:2, lg:2, xs:2, sm:2} },   
    Style :       { prop: "style",   classes: { md:1, lg:1, xs:2, sm:1} },    
  };
```

Above data implementing the value in html. So I want to hide from here only(Javascript Controller) **Style**

I want to put some condition with:

```
Style:{prop: "style", classes: { md:1, lg:1, xs:2, sm:1} }
```

I want to hide in some condition and displaying in other condition. Can I get outside from $scope.sort and if condition is satisfied then push to$scope.sort?

Comment: How about changing the name of property so it won't be used if your condition is met? e.g. rename _style_ for example to _styleHidden_

Comment: @blewherself. I want to hide style in some condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let styleContainer = $scope.sort.Style
    if (your condition)
      $scope.sort.Style = {}
```

will return:

```
{
    National :    { prop: "Country", classes: { md:2, lg:2, xs:1, sm:2} },
    'Passport #': { prop: "tNumber", classes: { md:2, lg:1, xs:2, sm:2} },
    Name :        { prop: "name",    classes: { md:2, lg:2, xs:2, sm:2} },   
    Style :       { }
};
```

To get Style object back use:

```
$scope.sort.Style = styleContainer
```

Comment: I dont want to change much more data

Comment: then tweak your code logic to ignore `Style` property in special conditions

Comment: Thanks a lot for save my time.